# How do I know when to cleanup the stack

Tags: assembly

I have a function in C & C++ that looks like:

```
__declspec(dllexport) bool CreateSocket(SSLSocket* ssl_info);
```

I believe that by default should use the `cdecl` calling convention.

If in assembly I import the module and do:

```
push sockinfo
call [CreateSocket]
```

Do I have to do: `add esp, 0x04` to restore the stack? Or is it restored automatically because it is an imported function? I ask this because for `printf` which is `cdecl` convention and imported, I have to clean up the stack myself. For `WINAPI` I don't have to do that.

Do I have to do this for exported/all functions or just for functions I write myself?

Comment: By default it uses whatever you set as your project's default calling convention.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I was looking at your article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/08/48616.aspx to learn the differences. Very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanup responsibility is the same whether the function is imported or integrated in the calling module. It's the calling convention alone that dictates who should do the cleanup.